# SQL Server Identity Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Looking for some help, as this SQL thing is new to me.   I was required to copy data from one table to another used for a billing application.  To do so, I simply copied the entire table using SELECT INTO statement.  The application now refuses to insert new records into the table that I had copied.  I am using SQL Server 2008, and suggest it has something to do with the Identity column, but not sure.  As stated above, this is all new to me.  Any help or suggestions where to start would be awesome.  Thank-you in advance.

The table that I copies looked like such...

```
InsuranceID       int              IDENTITY,
Insurance_ID       varchar(20),
Insurance_Name     varchar(100),
Address            varchar(100),
```

..  And so on.
This is the stored procedure used to insert new records into the table.

```
 Insert Into tblInsuranceCompanies
    (Insurance_ID,
    InsuranceName,
    InsuranceTypeID,
    Telephone,
    Extension,
    Fax,
    Address,
    City,
    State,
    Zip_Code)
Values
    (@InsuranceID,
    @Name,
    @TypeID,
    @Telephone,
    @Extension,
    @Fax,
    @Address,
    @City,
    @State,
    @Zip)

SELECT @@IDENTITY AS InsuranceID
```

Comment: can you share your insert statement?

Comment: And the exact error message you receive.

Comment: The error is received when an end-user try's to add another record through the application.  "Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'"

Comment: The insert statement is a stored procedure.  Here is the code within that procedure....

Comment: Ugh, you have columns `InsuranceID` and `Insurance_ID` that mean different things? And you use `@InsuranceID` to insert into `Insurance_ID`? No wonder there is confusion here.

Comment: Yeah,  this is something I have to deal with, but I definitely see what you are saying.  I had no choice in the matter, and it wont be changing either.

Comment: Hey, how is it possible. you are having a primary key in the column & you want to insert new value same as existing. Not possible at all if I understood your question. Simply disable or drop the constraint then try to insert new value.

Comment: The new table has identity defined? If not, you are trying to insert a dbnull to InsuranceID

Comment: Once again, please define what `refuses to insert` means, by posting the **actual error message**.

Comment: I did post the actual error message...
Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'.

Comment: Error message sounds like `c#/vb error`. If so, please show the code and schema of the table data inserting into.

Comment: You should add that information to the question, and since the error is not coming from SQL Server, you should also include your application code.

Comment: Like Aaron said, the error message looks Dot Net in nature, not a TSQL issue.  Run a simple test insert from SSMS with sample data, if it works, it is your code.

Comment: The insert does work.  Unfortunately, this application was purchased for a vendor and was very poorly built.  Support is just a shitty.  You are correct, as it is .net.  At this point I am about to give up and just have the employees provide me with the information that needs to be inserted and do it myself on the back end.  Sorry for all the confusion everyone, and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First I thought it is an Identity_Insert problem, which I suggested this:
before trying to insert data you can use SET IDENTITY_INSERT products ON

like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT products ON
GO

INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE
SELETC * FROM TempTable
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT products OFF
GO
```

but after noticing that the Identity column  is not there in the select list, and since all the columns definitions are NOT NULL, i guess one of the values you are trying to insert is null which is causing the error.

Comment: If you look at the `INSERT` statement, you'll see the OP is not trying to insert into the `IDENTITY` column...